# Android Play In-App Review pop up not supporting dark mode

Tags: android, google-play, android-support-library, android-darkmode

How to support dark mode for In-App review flow (review pop up) when application is in dark mode?

I have implemented android play in-app review flow. Flow working correctly but review pop is shown in light mode when application is in dark mode.

Comment: I don't think you can customise that since that flow view is provided by Google Play.

Comment: I am not trying to customize it. Application is supporting dark mode. Review dialog is   always in light mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize it by providing a different theme via [`ContextThemeWrapper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper), something like that:

```kotlin
val isNightMode = // code to check the current theme
val themeResId = if (isNightMode) {
      // provide theme for dark
} else {
      // provide theme for light
}

// create the contextWrapper with the theme
val themedContext = ContextThemeWrapper(context, themeResId)
val reviewManager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(themedContext)
val reviewInfoTask = reviewManager.requestReviewFlow()
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Can you show me the themes you applied?

Comment: val themedContext = ContextThemeWrapper(activity, R.style.ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Dark)